Data access to SAS
I hope this question is not off-topic, and apologize if it is. I'm not a data scientist per se, but as the person in charge of data architecture in my organization, I'd like to check my understanding about SAS.
Am I right in my understanding that SAS data is stored as data files, with one file per data set (and, by the way, can a data file contain multiple tables)? So, in order to access the data, each file must first be located, retrieved and opened by an application (such as SAS, but also others)? And would I be correct in my understanding that it makes SAS implementations such as the Life Science Analytics Framework a class of data stores different from an RDBMS where data can be stored in a single database?
So, if I am right, is it correct to assume that running a query over multiple data sets would first imply retrieving and loading each file?
Thanks in advance!

Note: the background of my question is to understand the accessibility of SAS data from non-SAS applications, e.g. BI applications.

